# Netlogo: extracting informtion from an agent

Tags: netlogo

In this example, dogs is the name of breeds. I want to perform different tasks depending on the attribute of AAA. For example, if it has a size attribute, size > 10 [ do task 1 ] when size <= 10  [ do task 2 ], etc. How can I extract attributes of AAA?

```
let AAA one-of dogs-here
if AAA != nobody [

]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
ask one-of dogs-here
[ if AAA > 10 
  [ forward 1
  ]
]
```

But it's important to understand why this works and that's about what NetLogo refers to as "context". When you say `ask one-of dogs-here [` and open the square bracket, you are changing context to the selected dog. In some sense, the computer is now taking the perspective of the dog and that dog is now "I" (or actually `self` in NetLogo) and the following commands apply to the particular dog.

If you're wanting to extract information about some other agent, then you use `of`, such as: `if [AAA] of turtle 0 > 10` ....